# Azure AD App API Permissions - Where to get the id of the permission being granted

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform

I'm trying to grant API Permissions on an App registration programatically using terraform. 
I dont know how to get the id of the permission that i want to grant. I've tried copy and paste of a permission used elsewhere from the manifest file, but it doesnt look to be that simple.

[image: broken permission]

This description of the setting is from the Terraform documentation.

*id - (Required) The unique identifier for one of the OAuth2Permission or AppRole instances that the resource application exposes.*

Does anyone know how to get the permission guids that are used here? are they specific to an app registration? I'm guessing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` in the terraform is not that in your screenshot, in your screenshot, it is the consent displayname of the permission, not the `id`, it just happens to be a guid.

To get the `id`, you could use the [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) powershell as below.

For example, get the `id` of the `xxx-nex-kv-access` API delegated permission like your screenshot.

1.Find the service principal.

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "xxx-nex-kv-access"
```

The command will list all the service principals related to `xxx-nex-kv-access`, make sure which one you need, then copy the `ObjectId` and `AppId` of it. (If there is no result, you can use `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` with no parameter to list all the service principal and find the one you need.)

2.Use the `ObjectId` to get the delegated permission.

```
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId "<ObjectId>"
$sp.Oauth2Permissions | select Id,AdminConsentDisplayName,Value
```

[image]

The `Id` is that you want, in the terraform, specify that like below.

```
    required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "<AppId>"

    resource_access {
      id   = "<Id>"
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }
```

**Besides**, you should notice the `type` property has two vaules, `Scope` and `Role`, you should know the `Scope` is `Delegated permission` and `Role` is `Application permission`.

So if you want to add the `Application permission` permission, you need to use the command as below, then in the terraform, use `type = "Role"`.

```
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId "<ObjectId>"
$sp.AppRoles | select Id,DisplayName,Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. I'm stuck at the point where you pull the oauth permissions off the SP. It doesn't pull anything back, but I'm assuming that all SPs should have permissions set by default?

Comment: @bytejunkie It is not by default, the permissions were exposed by the AD App(App registration). If you get nothing, it means the AD App of the service principal was not exposed as API. More details about how to expose APis for your AD App, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis).

Comment: @bytejunkie Actually, you could just test it with a Microsoft Application, e.g. Azure AD Graph. You can find a service principal in your tenant, its DisplayName is `Windows Azure Active Directory`, get it via `$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Windows Azure Active Directory"`, it has the static `AppId` with `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`.  Then use `$sp.Oauth2Permissions | select Id,AdminConsentDisplayName,Value` see the delegated permissions.

Comment: @bytejunkie In one word, you can understand the Azure AD Graph is an AD App in another tenant, and your tenant installed it, then there will be a service princiapl of the App in your tenant. You can also expose your app as APIs, the other people then will be able to use it.

Comment: I dont see any app permissions when running the commands against Windows Azure Active Directory. Am i missing some permissions in AAD?

Comment: @bytejunkie Could you get the `$sp` successfully?

Comment: definitely. listed out the id and then used that, even though its a step extra.

Comment: @bytejunkie What is your user type? And what is the version of your `AzureAD` powershell module? How about run the commands in the [cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview)?

Comment: the issue i was having was purely down to the fact I was using the wrong powershell module. I was trying to pull the permissions back with the Az module, which obviously doesnt have the same outputs as the AzureAD module (I had an issue with the Azure AD module, which I've now fixed). Thanks so much for your perseverance.

Comment: @bytejunkie Glad to hear that.